# ASP.NET Core: Add custom argument to the method using Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add a custom argument to the method using a custom action filter.

#### What I tried

I created an action filter that injects an argument using `context.ActionArguments`. After this change, a GET call using this action filter returns 415 Unsupported Media Type if I do not specify Context-Type as application/json.

Action Filter

```
    public class AddArgumentActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            string itemId = context.RouteData.Values["itemId"] as string;
            MyClass item = await db.GetItemAsync(itemId); // Some call to the database
            context.ActionArguments["item"] = item;
            await next();
        }
    }
```

Controller Method

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("items/{itemId}")]
        [AddArgumentActionFilter]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RoomWebEntity>> GetItem(MyClass item)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Sending GET request to `items/{itemId}` returns 415 Unsupported Media Type. If I specify Content-Type as application/json in the header then the call is successful.

There seemed to be some validation done when an action argument is an object. Is there a way to add an argument under the hood without changing the behavior of the HTTP call?

#### Output of `dotnet --info`

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.200-preview-014883
 Commit:    4e2a0ee959

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18363
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200-preview-014883\
```

Comment: Why you can not retrieve the item in the action method itself? Since you are sending object to the action method it needs to know how to parse incoming request content to create the item object. When you pass content-type it uses json serialization. That's why you need to pass the header. The simplest solution is not to use attribute for such operations

Comment: Many of my methods need to retrieve the item in the same manner so I want to avoid code duplication using the action filter. Same approach as this blog: https://blog.vincentcos.tel/using-action-filters-to/

Comment: Would you try the custom model binder as the document shows at first line .

Comment: Ah I missed that line. Thanks I’ll give it a try.